# Php can't find tidy

Tags: php, docker, alpine-linux, tidy, phpdocx

I am using a  `php7` in `docker container` to run a service based on phpdocx library. It needs `tidy` and some other extensions installed and active to work. I have installed `php-tidy` however I am getting following warning.

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'tidy' (tried: /usr/lib/php7/modules/tidy (Error loading shared library /usr/lib/php7/modules/tidy: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php7/modules/tidy.so (Error relocating /usr/lib/php7/modules/tidy.so: _zval_ptr_dtor: symbol not found)) in Unknown on line 0`

**Dockerfile**

```sh
FROM php:7.3.2-cli-alpine3.9
USER root


COPY . code
WORKDIR code


RUN apk update && apk add php-tidy && apk add php-zip &&  apk add php-curl && apk add php-sodium

# RUN sed -i s/;extension=tidy/extension=tidy/ -f /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-development
# RUN sed -i s/;extension=tidy/extension=tidy/ -f /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-production

COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-development
COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-production

COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini


CMD php -S 0.0.0.0:8080
```

**Output from docker shell**

*on running phpinfo()*

```
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sodium.ini
```

```sh
# vi /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

extension=tidy 

[Tidy]                                                                     
; The path to a default tidy configuration file to use when using tidy         
; http://php.net/tidy.default-config                                            
;tidy.default_config = /usr/local/lib/php/default.tcfg                         

; Should tidy clean and repair output automatically?                            
; WARNING: Do not use this option if you are generating non-html content       
; such as dynamic images                                                       
; http://php.net/tidy.clean-output                                             
tidy.clean_output = Off   



; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
extension_dir = "/usr/lib/php7/modules/"
; On windows:
;extension_dir = "ext"
```

```sh
#ls /usr/lib/php7/modules/
curl.so    sodium.so  tidy.so    zip.so
```

Comment: Have you checked if there is a package called php7.3-tidy? Might be an misleading error because of a version mismatch. Just a thought.

Comment: There is a package `php7-tidy`. I installed this on but this one didn't help either.

Comment: Do you mean `php7.3-tidy` or are you still testing `php7-tidy` ? Have you installed `libtidy`? `sudo apt install libtidy-dev libtidy5` (ref: http://php.net/manual/en/tidy.installation.php)

Comment: Can you search for every file tidy.so in your machine to see if the path is good? `sudo find / -name tidy.so`

Answer (score 1):

There are docker commands to install php libraries. So instead of using linux command eg: `apk add php-tidy`  using `docker-php-ext-install tidy` solved my problem. Below is the docker file that works.

```html
FROM php:7


ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

USER root
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y libzip-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libtidy-dev
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y libcurl3
RUN apt-get install -y libcurl3-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip
RUN docker-php-ext-install curl
RUN docker-php-ext-install tidy
RUN docker-php-ext-enable zip
RUN docker-php-ext-enable curl
RUN docker-php-ext-enable tidy

COPY . code
WORKDIR code

EXPOSE 8080
CMD php -S 0.0.0.0:8080
```

Answer (score 1):

On Debian Bullseye based Dockerfile:

```bash
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libtidy-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-install tidy && \
    docker-php-ext-enable tidy && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* # cleanup
```

Answer (score 1):

On Debian 12:

`libtidy-dev` must be installed

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libtidy-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-install tidy
```

And restart `php-fpm` service or Docker.